# Certain languages are not available in postman; is there a way to enable it?

Tags: postman

I am trying to use postman for certain languages like PHP NodeJS and Javascript. But the option is disabled; and there's an arrow icon juxtaposed. Maybe I am missing something?

Please appreciate any input. Thanks.

Comment: Is this on the experimental code gen? There is a toggle in `Settings > General` to switch from the standard one to the newer feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the settings that Danny mentioned, I had to turn on Experimental Codegen mode; then there where all kinds of options. For instance there was an XmlHttpRequest under Javascript plus there was a jQuery option etc.